# SwiftUI DispatchQueue asyncAfter stops working correctly after ten scheduled tasks

Tags: swift, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch

If I run the code below, it counts correctly to 10 and then skips every odd number.

If you let it run beyond 20, it will start skipping more and more (the output will be like 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-12-14-16-18-20-23-26-29 ...).

Couldn't find documentation of e.g. a limit of scheduled tasks, so asking you :)
Learning SwiftUI since yesterday, so pardon if it's an obvious question.

If it's scheduled in a different DispatchQueue than main, it makes no difference.

Thanks for helping!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter : Int = 0
    
    func buttonTap() {
        let time : DispatchTime = .now()
        
        var delay : Double = 0
        
        for _ in 1...50 {
            
            delay = delay + 0.2
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time + delay) {
                counter += 1
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Color(.black)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            Text(String(counter))
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .padding()
            
            Text("Button")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .offset(y: 50)
                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                    buttonTap()
                })
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any defect here - counter is updated faster then UI, so you don't see all cases. Why do you do that?

Comment: I am making a breath meditation app which has delays of several seconds...and still, it for example just overleaps a pause of a few seconds and directly begins the next task...don't think, this is because of slow UI updates? Or is it? And even in the more complex app, problems start after ten tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an odd behavior, and it even occurs for much longer time intervals between events (for example, 2 seconds).

Consider using a `Timer` instead:

You can use multiple single fire timers that work just like your separate dispatches:

```
func buttonTap() {
    
    var delay : Double = 0
    
    for _ in 1...50 {
        
        delay = delay + 0.2
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: false) { timer in
            self.counter += 1
        }
        
    }
}
```

or a single timer that fires every `0.2` seconds:

```
func buttonTap() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { timer in
        self.counter += 1
        if counter == 50 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working like this! Am I allowed to mark your question as the solution (since it shows another way and doesn't explain the DispatchQueue behavior)?

Comment: Yes, as the question author, you can mark any answer as the solution as you see fit.  You can also change the accepted answer if a better one comes along, so it's not locked in stone.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is known as timer coalescing, where independently scheduled events that occur within 10% of each other will be coalesced together, and will be run at the same time. This is a power saving feature.

There are a variety of solutions to avoid coalescing:

- use a repeating timer;
- schedule each iteration in the completion handler of the prior iteration; or
- create “strict” GCD timers that won’t be subject to coalescing.

The repeating timer is the most common solution.